# How can i append pandas dataframe rows under another df rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframe, one df has the id column and another df has values i want to add df1.

**df1:**

| id | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | rose |
| 2 | blue | rose |
| 3 | yellow | rose |

**df2**

| id | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | green | car |
| null | grey | car |

i want to append df2 values to df1 but i need to append data for all id numbers.

**output i am trying to get :**

| id | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | rose |
| 1 | green | car |
| 1 | grey | car |
| 2 | blue | rose |
| 2 | green | car |
| 2 | grey | car |
| 3 | yellow | rose |
| 3 | green | car |
| 3 | grey | car |

i tried with the for and if else statements but im stuck it

Comment: Result you added is expected or you got it?

Comment: no i want to get this result

Comment: Do you want to repeat the df2 with each row in df1, as shown in result?

Comment: yes its true i will also take information from the previous line (for id column only)

Comment: @AdityaSoni do u have any idea?

Comment: Could you please give an example with dummy values instead of cell 1 and 2, it will be helpful to understand with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try cross appling ids from the first dataframe with second one and the concatenating the results:

```py
data = [[1,'red',   'rose'], [2,'blue', 'rose'], [3,'yellow', 'rose']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["id", "Column A", "Column B"])

data1 = [['green', 'car' ],['grey','car']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=["Column A", "Column B"])


pd.concat([df, df[['id']].merge(df1, how='cross')])
```

Note that this will contain duplicates if some id from `df1` will already have data as one of the rows in `df2`.

Output:

| id | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | rose |
| 2 | blue | rose |
| 3 | yellow | rose |
| 1 | green | car |
| 1 | grey | car |
| 2 | green | car |
| 2 | grey | car |
| 3 | green | car |
| 3 | grey | car |

Comment: @AdityaSoni can you please elaborate?

Comment: @GuruStron this code appends data to end of the df1. i want to duplicate all data for each id. df2 not contains id column ids are empty

Comment: @padawan it creates duplicates for every id and appends it to the end. If needed you can add sorting by id.

Comment: @padawan added full repro.

Comment: its help me for this case i edited excel for details thank you

Comment: @padawan what are you missing then?